# separate a variable into two using SH/BASH

Tags: bash, sh

I have a number I get from `cat` like this: "(number1,number2)" I want to split the values into two different variables.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to do it in a single line is to use `grep`:

```
read -r var1 var2 < <(grep -o '[0-9]*' file.txt)
```

A more robust way that does not use external programs (and hence is faster) is to use `$BASH_REMATCH`:

```
if [[ "$(<file.txt)" =~ ^\((.*),(.*)\)$ ]]; then
    var1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    var2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

The basic idea in this method is that we read the file contents into a string (with `"$(<file.txt)"`) and then we immediately test that string against a regular expression (with the `=~` operator). The regular expression include two capturing groups, which we later retrieve from the `$BASH_REMATCH` array. The regular expression extracts the groups by ignoring the `(` and `)` at the beginning and at the end of the string and finds the `,` that separates them.

Comment: I would rather use `read` to get the data from file: `read -r line < file.txt` and then use the regex on this variable.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf What are the advantages of that approach? That you read a single line?

Comment: Another quick and dirty way: `IFS='(,) ' read -r _ var1 var2 < file.txt`. Very dirty.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to read a single line (and not spawn a subshell).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Does `$(<file.txt)` spawn a subshell? I thought it didn't.

Comment: `strace bash -c 'a=$(< .bashrc)' 2>&1 | grep clone`.

Comment: Could someone explain how you are filtering the characters in the BASH_REMATCH method?

Comment: @1431 I added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: @redneb i put this in a file: '#/bin/sh
if [[ "$(cat /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light)" =~ ^\((.*),(.*)\)$ ]]; then
    left1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    right2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
'

and get: 'test.sh: 2: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")'

Comment: Try with the following shebang: `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: What OS is that? What is the version of bash (`echo $BASH_VERSION`)?

Comment: @redneb the command outputs: 4.3.11(1)-release im running lubuntu 14.04

Comment: Create a script with the 4 lines as I gave them in my answer, exactly, only change the name of the file, nothing else.

Comment: @redneb thanks it worked after some tweaking in bash config :)